# Cover of the space obtained by gluing the boundary circle of a Möbius strip to the torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Consider the space $X$ obtained from identifying the boundary circle of a Möbius strip to a circle $S^{1} \times \{x_{0}\}$ of the torus $S^{1} \times S^{1}$.  One can use Van-Kampen's theorem to obtain the following presentation of the fundamental group:

$$\pi_{1}(X) = \langle a, b: ab^{2} =b^{2}a \rangle .$$

Suppose we consider the homomorphism $\phi: \pi_{1}(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ that sends $a \mapsto 1$ and $b \mapsto -1$.

**I was having trouble finding the cover corresponding to the kernel of $\phi$**

So far the approach I've taken has involved understanding the universal cover and understanding how the deck transformations act on that space.

*EDIT(12/15/19): As pointed out in the comments (see there for a link to right description), this universal cover description is wrong:*

*The Universal Cover:*
In particular, since the universal cover of both Möbius strip and the torus is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I believe that the universal cover $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ should be homeomorphic to the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that consists of the $xy$-plane with a $xz$ plane going through each line $y=k$ (in the $xy$ plane) for each integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

*Deck transformations acting on the cover:*

The way I think the Deck transformations act on the universal cover is by restrictions of $a: (x,y,z) \mapsto (x+1,y,z)$ and $b: (x,y,z)\mapsto (x+1,y,-z).$

**If this is all okay, then the cover corresponding to the kernel of $\phi$ should indeed be the quotient space obtained by the action of $\tilde{X}$ and the action of the group generated by $a$ and $b^{2}$. But I am having trouble understanding this.**

Comment: The universal covering space description in this post is incorrect. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478166/describe-universal-cover-of-x-where-pi-1x-langle-b-c-mid-bc2-c2b-rangle/3478583#3478583) for a correct description. What's described in this post is only a small part of the universal covering space.

Comment: Thank you, I meant to edit this some time ago but forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $M$ and $T$ the Möbius band and the torus, which I will identify with their respective images in the quotient space $X$. Fix a basepoint $e_0=\overline{(x_0,x_0)}\in X$ (by a bar I mean the class in the quotient space) and denote by $H$ the kernel of $\phi$, which is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,e_0)$.

Because $\pi_1(X,e_0)/H\simeq \mathbb Z_2$, $H$ has index two in $\pi_1(X,e_0)$. Hence you can try to create "by hand" a covering space 
$$p:Y\longrightarrow X$$
of index two such that $p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))=H$.

**Analysis of the problem:** Assume that we have such a covering space. Because $b\not\in H=p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))$, $b$ can't lift to a loop in  $Y$, it has to lift to a path with different endpoints (i.e it acts non-trivially on the fiber). This fact will tell use how to reconstruct $p$. The restriction 
$$p:p^{-1}(M)\longrightarrow M$$ 
is still a covering space of index two. Therefore it is either a trivial covering space $M\times\{1,2\}\to M$ or it is the 2 sheeted cover $C\to M$ by a cylinder $C\simeq S^1\times [0,1]$. The first case is not possible because we could find lifts of $b$ which are loops in $b$, so the idea is that $M$ is covered by a cylinder.

**Construction of** $p$**:** Take two tori $T_0=S^1\times S^1$ and $T_1=S^1\times S^1$ and a cylinder $C=S^1\times [0,1]$. Identify the circle $S^1\times \{i\}$ of the bourndary of $C$ with the circle $S_i^1\times\{x_0\}$ of $T_i$ using the identity map, for $i=0,1$. Denote by $Y$ the quotient space. Define $p:Y\to X$ as follows:

- $p$ maps $T_0$ to $T$ via the identity map.
- $p$ sends $C$ to $M$ as does the (unique) 2-sheeted covering space $C\to M$. Note that this map sends the boundary circles $S^1\times \{0\}$ and $S^1\times \{1\}$ of $C$ to the boundary of $M$ but with different orientations.
- $p$ sends $T_1$ to $T$ by the map $(x,y)\to(-x,y)$ (here I can't choose the identity because $p$ has to be coherent with its value on $C$).

If you do a drawing of $Y$, which makes things way easier to understand, you can convince yourself that $p$ is a covering space, and by construction it has degree two.

Finally we have to understand why $p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))=H$ for some $y_0$ in the fiber $p^{-1}(e_0)$. Lets write $p^{-1}(e_0)=\{y_0,y_1\}$, where $y_i$ is the element in the fiber which is in $T_i$. There are two paths $\gamma$ and $\gamma^\prime$ in $C$ which goes from $x_0$ to $x_1$ such that $[p(\gamma)]=b$ and $[p(\gamma^\prime)]=b^{-1}$ (they each do a half turn in the cylinder and goes from one boundary to the other).
Let $n\in \Bbb Z$. Take $\alpha$ to be the element of $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ which goes once in the path $\gamma$ or $\gamma^\prime$, then does $n$ turns in the circle $\{x_0\}\times S^1$ in $T_2$ then comes back to $y_1$ via $\overline{\gamma}$ or $\overline{\gamma^\prime}$. Then $p_*(\alpha)$ is either 
$$b a^nb\quad\text{or}\quad ba^nb^{-1}\quad\text{or}\quad b^{-1}a^nb\quad\text{or}\quad b^{-1}a^nb^{-1}.$$
If you take $\alpha$ to be the loop which goes once around the circle $\{x_0\}\times S^1$ in $T_1$, you get $p_*(\alpha)=a^n$. This shows the inclusion $H\subset p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))$ if you know that $H$ is generated by the elements above (which I claim is true). To prove the inclusion $p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))\subset H$, I think the best way is to understand what are the generators of $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ (by using Van Kampen for example) and see that they are all mapped to $H$ by $p_*$.

---

Now that I wrote the arguments I have the feeling that all this is very confusing without a drawing, I'll add one latter I think. I have thought about your argument using the universal covering space but I think that the universal covering space of $X$ is complicated to see (at least I don't see how it could be the space you described as union of planes). Even if it is the case and you have the good universal covering space, I think that your deck transformations are incorrect: first they commute and also the quotient space doesn't seem compact (the transformations doesn't act on the coordinate $y$).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed post. I agree that my deck transformations are off.  I can maybe explain my thinking regarding the universal cover in a bit. Hopefully by tomorrow. I’ll try to think about what you wrote too.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I follow and believe the 2-cover. For the universal cover, I thought that one could use that both the universal cover of the Mobius band and the torus is homeomorphic to a plane. For the space $X$, we have that we have that the boundary circle of the Mobius band is glued to say the $S^{1} \times \{x_{0}\}$ direction, which in the universal cover of the torus  which we can think of as corresponding to the path moving from "left to right". It is along translates of this path that I wanted to glue in the planes corresponding to the universal cover of the Mobius band.

Comment: @user135520 I understand your thought for why the universal cover would be a space like this. Now $X$ and $Y$ have the same universal cover, but its not clear to me why that universal cover of $Y$ would be so simple. It looks like the universal cover will do things like the universal cover of the wedge sum of two circle. When we glue two circles together, which both have universal cover $\Bbb R$, the universal is not as simple as the union of lines $(x=n)$ and $(y=n)$.